# Cross Origin Resource Sharing Headers not working only for safari

Tags: image, html, canvas, safari, cors

I'm using rackspace to host my image files that are drawn on an html5 canvas object.  Because of an HTML security feature when saving a canvas I have to use CORS (Cross Origin Resource Headers) to make save work.

I have tested my code on **Chrome, IE with Chrome Frame, and Firefox**, and none of them give me a security error after I added to the image request headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

and I have added the following attribute to all the images drawn on to the canvas

```
crossOrigin = "anonymous"
```

However, for some reason Safari still gives a security error.

```
SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
```

Any thoughts as to why this is happening on safari(desktop 5.1.7, and ipad) versions?  I have checked the documentation and everything I have read says that Safari 4+ supports CORS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari 5.2 in beta solves the problem. So it looks like Safari does not yet support cors for images in released versions.  The same goes for iOS safari

Comment: `Safari 5.2 in beta solves the problem` where did you get this information? I couldn't find it from internet.

Comment: @bob This is from 2012 but 5.2 was never released and instead repackaged as safari 6 I believe.